# Python3- Replace a String Value with a Date from DateTime class

Tags: python

I am trying to format the due date column of my dataframe from strings to dates from the datetime class. It seems to work within my for-loop, however, when I leave the loop, the values in my dataframe do not change.

`df.replace()` is obsolete, and `.iat` and `.at` do not work either. Code below. Thanks!

```
for x in df['due date']:
    if type(x) == str:
        date = x.split('/')
        month = int(date[0])
        day = int(date[1])
        year = int(date[2].split(' ')[0])
        formattedDate = dt.date(year, month, day)
        df.at[x, "due date"] = formattedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something here, you can just pass the column to the built in 'to_datetime' function.

```
df['due date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['due date'],format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

That is assuming your date format is something like: 02/24/2021
If you need to change the date format, see the following:
[strftime and strptime behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)